Login Flow works but content doesn't appear when the user logs in via SSO or out-of-the-box login form
Issue: Users try to log into an Experience portal, but the implemented EULA login flow (Screen flow )does not show when they sign in via SSO through Okta or an out-of-the-box login form.

The portal uses Visualforce as the framework.
If I click on the workspace section the page redirects me to the
Experience site URL and I can’t access this page because a VPN is
needed.
Users with VPN access can’t open the workspace from the only two
sites created with the Visualforce framework. (They see a message
stating “We can't load the page. Please click Refresh.)
When the user tries to log in the landing page shows the error
message: “Page Not Found:/loginflow/lightningLoginFlow.apexp”
Profiles using the login flow already have access to the EULA flow
and its fields.
The login flows are assigned to the right profiles.

UPDATES:

Users saw the message “Page Not
Found:/loginflow/lightningLoginFlow.apexp” because the checkbox
from the Domains section "Allow Access to Standard Salesforce
Pages" was disabled.

The issue appears in Google and Safari browser

The issue appears in Incognito Mode

The profile of the test user and the profile used in the login
flow is the same

I already provided the access run flow to the test users'
profiles.
Flow appears as successful in the debug log but nothing is
shown in the UI


